# How to create an array of square of given numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array of numbers which gives the square of those numbers; for example I tried this but it does not work:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 30, 50, 7, 83, 670]
let n = array.map((num)=>{
return num % num
})

console.log(n)
```

Comment: `let arr = [1, 2, 30, 50, 7, 83, 670];
 let n = array.map((num)=>{ return num * num })
console.log(n)`

Use `*` for multiplication

Comment: If you want to create an array of the square of each number (`[1, 4, 900...]`) why are you using the remainder ([`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)) operator instead of multiplication? Is this a misunderstanding of the math operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is a small problem in your code.

Just replace ( % ) sign with ( * ) between num % num.

The code should be like this:

```
let arr = [ 1, 2, 30, 50, 7, 83, 670 ] 
let n = arr.map((num){
return num * num
}) 
console.log(n).
```

The expected output should be the square of the numbers in the given array!

Comment: `arr.map()`, not `array.map()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `n * n` to square a number `n`.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 30, 50, 7, 83, 670].map(n => n * n);
console.log(arr);
```